# UITableViewCell, Hiding and displaying them on a toggle

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can you hide or show a UITableViewCell based on a toggle from a UISwicth? (Toggle on, it displays the cell and vise versa).. Example: a cell for extra options pops up when the swicth for "Enable password" is turned on.

Comment: You should conditionally update the number of rows i that section and call a `reloadData` on your tableview. i.e. Your datasource object should return different number of rows based on the switch's condition, and a call to `reloadData` will make sure your table view is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you toggle the switch , you can change the height of the particular cell (using indexpath.row) to zero

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == YOUR_REQUIRED_INDEX)
       return 0;
    return DEFAULT_HEIGHT;    
}
```

and when you turn off the switch button , you can set the particular tableview row's height to your default.Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

When switch is turned on, add one more entry in your table view data source(data need to be loaded in extra cell) and call method

Swift

```
yourTableview.reloadData()
```

Objective C

```
[yourTableview reloadData];
```

and when switch is turned off, remove that added data from data source and reload table data again. Fell free to ask in case of any confusion.

Comment: How can I add a fade to it when the cells appearing and disappearing?